# Right angles in triangles formed in trapezoid

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the following trapezoid, is angle A in triangle ABC a right angle even though it isn't labeled as such? And if so what property would we use to determine that? I was able to get the correct area for triangle ABC using Heron's formula after finding side AC using the Pythagorean theorem. Therefore, angle A in triangle ABC must be a right angle, but I can't find the property.

[image]

Comment: Using the Pythagorean Theorem on the right triangle AEB to determine EB, calculating CE from the difference in lengths and then finding AC using the Pythagorean Theorem on AEC will enable you to check if CAB is a right triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Because by Pythagorean Theorem on $\Delta AEB$, $|EB| = 9$ and therefore $|CE| = 25 - 9 = 16$. Then by Pythagorean Theorem on $\Delta AEC$, $|AC| = 20$. Then $\Delta ABC$ has sides $15, 20, 25$ which is a Pythagorean triple. Therefore, $\angle CAB = 90^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

From the information given it is easy to assess the claim.

First render $|EB|=9$ with the Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle ABE$.  Then render $|CE|=16$ by difference along $\overline{CB}$.  Apply the Pythagorean Theorem to $\triangle ACE$ to get $|AE|$ and then check your result against the Pythagorean Theorem in $\triangle BCA$.  You should find that the claim is true.

Bonus:  Draw the perpendicular to $\overline{CB}$ from $D$ which intersects $\overline{CB}$ at $F$ prove that $|DA|=11$ is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $$AE^2 = CE\times EB$$

then the triangle $ABC$ is a right triangle and the angle $CAB =90$ degrees.

We have $AE^2 =144$ and it is easy to see that $CE\times EB =16 \times 9 =144$$

Thus the answer is yes.